# How select query works in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a select query that selects data on streaming. Suppose I ran the query and data count is 100; while retrieving the data, a few more rows are inserted, for example 10 more. Now my question is: will the select return 100 or 110 rows?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Though I would expect all of them to return 100 not 110.

Comment: SQL is transacted, CCR,  so it will show 100. 
CCR = Commitment, Concurrency and Recovery

Comment: DB2 allows you to INSERT at the same time that you SELECT, but this is really a special case... and it's more to get back calculated values, e.g. an identity.  SELECT FROM INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

This gets into Isolation in RDBMS environments. For example, in SQL Server, if I run a query that selects all COMMITTED data from a table, and at the time it has 100 rows, I will return 100 rows. If this table is currently being inserted into and those new rows are not yet committed, I will still return 100 rows (assuming the table is not locked). I have to rerun the query each time. The result set will not just magically get bigger. You have to issue a select each time you want to return data.

Now, if I am selecting UNCOMMITTED data and using something like NOLOCK, each time I run my select, I will return records that have not been committed yet. This means that each time I run my select, while the table is receiving new records, I will see those new records each time my data set is returned. This is helpful to see the newest records as they are coming in, but this can lead to dirty reads if for any reason that transaction fails or gets rolled back.